# Opencart on browser close session remain same but There is no item in its cart

Tags: php, linux, opencart

**opencart session remain same but its cart item are deleted when the browser reopen.. i want the session not deleted its item and it remain till 24 hours.my opencart session file in library is**

```
class Session {
public $data = array();

public function __construct() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'On');
        ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
        ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'On');

        //session_set_cookie_params(86400, '/');
        ini_set('session.cache_expire', '86400');
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '86400');
        ini_set('session.save_path','/home_directory_path/sessions');
        ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
        session_start();
        setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+86400);
    }

    $this->data =& $_SESSION;

}

public function getId() {
    return session_id();
}`
```

Comment: does `session` stay alive, when you close your browser once & re-open it. Are you still logged in your store?

Comment: yes session stays alive but cart item become empty when i close the browser...

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are closed/deleted when browser is closed. You need to start using cookies to achieve the results you are asking.

[PHP Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Comment: by this line "setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+86400);" the session is alive for 24 hour but the cart item is deleted after 3 or 4 hours